# How to use google sheets to fill in values that correspond to max values, based on grouping variable

Tags: google-sheets

I want to know how to use google sheets to fill in values that correspond to max values, based on grouping variable.

The grouping variable is called "Exercise category", the variable that contains the numerical scores used to determine max scores is called "Calibration".

For the variable called "PR?", I want the cell to say "Yes" if the if the corresponding cell value in the "Calibration" variable is the max score for all cells where the "Exercise category" matches.

For the variable "PR calibration", I want the cell to display the max score in the "Calibration" variable for all cells with with corresponding "Exercise category" variables that match.

For the variable "PR unit", I want the cell to display the max score in the "Unit" variable for all cells with with corresponding "Exercise category" variables that match.

Is this possible? If so, how?

__
__

The data I used are below, but it's not necessary to use:

```
Date    Exercise category   Calibration Unit    PR? PR value    PR Calibration  Count
04/22/2021  Front squat 32.5    kg              3
04/22/2021  Push press  30  kg              5
05/12/2021  Push jerk   35  kg              14
05/12/2021  Push press  35  kg              15
05/12/2021  Rows with dumbbells 20  lb              17
05/22/2021  Snatch  30  kg              26
05/28/2021  Snatch  30  kg              32
05/28/2021  Deadlift    40  kg              33
06/05/2021  Clean pulls     50  kg              38
06/10/2021  Snatch  20  kg              43
06/15/2021  Power cleans    30  kg              44
06/19/2021  Power snatch    30  kg              47
06/24/2021  Power cleans    40  kg              50
06/29/2021  Snatch  30  kg              52
07/06/2021  Power cleans    40  kg              56
07/08/2021  Snatch  40  kg              59
07/08/2021  OHP 50  kg              61
07/13/2021  Clean and Jerk  30  kg              62
07/20/2021  Power cleans    50  kg              65
07/22/2021  Snatch  30  kg              68
07/27/2021  OHP 50  kg              71
08/05/0201  Rows with dumbbells 15  lb              75
08/10/2021  Snatch  40  kg              76
08/12/2021  Power cleans    50  kg              78
08/12/2021  Back squat  80  kg              79
08/17/2021  Snatch  40  kg              81
08/17/2021  OHP 60  kg              83
08/19/2021  Deadlift    70  kg              86
08/23/2021  Snatch  40  kg              88
08/23/2021  Snatch pulls    55  kg              89
08/26/2021  Back squat  80  kg              92
08/26/2021  OHP 50  kg              93
02/24/2022  Snatch  30  kg              96
03/01/2022  Clean pulls 60  kg              100
03/05/2022  Split jerk  60  kg              104
03/05/2022  Front squat 70  kg              105
03/08/2022  Snatch  30  kg              107
03/10/2022  Push press  30  kg              112
03/10/2022  Rows with dumbbells 20  lb              113
03/19/2022  Push press  55  kg              120
03/19/2022  Rows with dumbbells 20  lb              121
03/22/2022  Snatch  30  kg              123
03/22/2022  Snatch pulls    60  kg              124
03/22/2022  Bench press with dumbbells  30  lb              125
03/29/2022  Clean pulls 70  kg              128
03/29/2022  OHP 50  kg              129
03/31/2022  Push press  50  kg              132
04/02/2022  Snatch pulls    65  kg              136
04/02/2022  Bench press with barbell    50  kg              137
04/05/2022  Cleans  55  kg              139
04/05/2022  Clean pulls 80  kg              140
04/05/2022  Front squat 90  kg              141
04/07/2022  Split jerk  65  kg              144
04/07/2022  Push press  55  kg              145
04/07/2022  Bench press with dumbbells  35  lb              146
04/07/2022  Rows with dumbbells 35  lb              147
04/09/2022  Snatch  40  kg              149
04/16/2022  Cleans  55  kg              152
04/19/2022  Front squat 65  kg              157
04/23/2022  Snatch  40  kg              160
04/23/2022  Back squat  100 kg              162
04/26/2022  Clean pulls 55  kg              166
04/26/2022  Bench press with dumbbells  35  lb              167
04/30/2022  Split jerk  60  kg              169
04/30/2022  Push press  60  kg              170
04/30/2022  Front squat 75  kg              171
05/07/2022  Clean and jerk  55  kg              174
05/07/2022  Front squat 80  kg              176
05/10/2022  Cleans  60  kg              178
05/14/2022  Split jerk  80  kg              180
05/14/2022  Push press  30  kg              181
05/14/2022  OHP 50  kg              182
05/17/2022  Cleans  55  kg              185
05/21/2022  Snatch  40  kg              187
05/21/2022  Snatch pulls    70  kg              188
05/21/2022  Back squat  85  kg              189
```

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Please also share the research you have already done and the formula attempts you have already made toward solving your own issues, as well as clearly describing or showing (in your spreadsheet) the results of your own formula attempts. Keep in mind that Stack is not a free formula or script writing service; it is a place where people can get a little information or "small help" on formulas or lines of script they have already written themselves and which they nearly have correct, or for which they can show a good amount of work toward solving the problem before coming to ask for help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I managed to get the google sheet to work for PR Value using =ArrayFormula(MAX(IF())), and for PR calibration using =INDEX(,match(MAX(IF()))